# Remove Return URL and redirect user to another page before login

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication, forms-authentication, response

I'm building an app where I'm using Forms authentication to authenticate the logged in users.

Login.aspx page contains other links to redirect users to another page but it won't redirect users to those pages unless logged in.

```
http://localhost:1607/Account/Login.aspx?
```

When I click on a link to redirect users to about.aspx
it goes back to login page with the following URL

```
http://localhost:1607/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAbout.aspx
```

how do I remove returnURL and redirect users to /about.aspx page?
web.config file has forms authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<location>` to allow all users, like this:

```
<location path="about.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

You need a separate `<location>` for each page/link you have.